# Does the Vivilion postcard pinning overflow to the next medal?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I have a Vivilion medal at 12 out of 15 and then pins 5 postcards for that model, would the medal be completed and the left over of 2 be brought over to the next medal?

Or would the new medal starts with 0 out of 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would the medal be completed and the left over of 2 be brought over to the next medal?

No.

> Or would the new medal starts with 0 out of 15?

Yes. You must claim and catch the Scatterbug encounter reward before pinning more postcards of that region in order for them to count.