# Postcards pinning and Vivillon medals in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

### How does postcards pinning work to count towards Vivillon medals?

- **Q: [Does the Vivilion postcard pinning overflow to the next medal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401836/does-the-vivilion-postcard-pinning-overflow-to-the-next-medal)**

  - A: No, it doesn't.
- **Q: What happens when I pin the postcards, then had to delete the pins when my postcard book is full?** Does the Vivillon medal progress then rollback too? (What if I already claimed the medal and caught the scatterbug before deleting the pin?)
- Q: If I pin a postcard from a friend, it counts towards the Vivillon medal progress. **But what if I haven't claimed/opened the gift that comes with the postcard, unpin it and re-pin it the next day?** Does it count towards teh Vivillon medal another time? Or it only happens the first time?
- **Q: What is the max no. of postcards/gifts I can receive from spinning gyms and pokestops?** It looks there after a certain no. of gifts I collected and sent, spinning stops/gyms no longer give me new gifts. There's no indication on how many gifts I can send or collect, unlike the daily limit on receiving gifts.
- Q: **What is the max no. of gifts I can receive daily?**  I frequently encounter the maxed limits on receiving gifts, but never actually kept a count on how many I can receive.
- Q: **There's a limit of 3 postcards I can pin when I send to my friends, and these 3 count towards Vivillon medal; is that right?** Or is the limit higer/lower?
- Q: **Is there an option to favorite some pinned post cards, and the delete everything else?** (Like how pokemons are transferred)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when I pin the postcards, then had to delete the pins when my postcard book is full? Does the Vivillon medal progress then rollback too?

No. Once you've received credit for the pin, you can safely unpin it with no adverse effects.

> If I pin a postcard from a friend, it counts towards the Vivillon medal progress. But what if I haven't claimed/opened the gift that comes with the postcard, unpin it and re-pin it the next day? Does it count towards the Vivillon medal another time?

No. Each individual gift will only count once.

> What is the max no. of postcards/gifts I can receive from spinning gyms and pokestops?

100 per day. Note that this figure does **not** include the gifts that you can receive from your buddy.

> What is the max no. of gifts I can receive daily?

I assume here you mean how many gifts you can *open*, which is currently 20, although events boosting this to 30 or 40 have been common recently.

> There's a limit of 3 postcards I can pin when I send to my friends, and these 3 count towards Vivillon medal; is that right?

That's correct. Each calendar day you can only receive 3 credits to the Vivillon medal from pinning your own gifts. There is theoretically no limit on how many gifts from your friends that you can pin in each day, but obviously you end up being limited by how many you can open in practice.  You can pin a gift without opening it, but then cannot receive another gift from that friend until the gift is opened.

> Is there an option to favorite some pinned post cards, and the delete everything else?

No.